# Build Failure After Migrating to Gradle 8.1.1:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on an Android project, and I recently decided to migrate from Gradle version 8.0.2 to 8.1.1. To assist with this, I used Android Studio's built-in AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) upgrade assistant.

Post-migration, I started facing a build failure that I hadn't encountered before. The error message from the build log is:

> e:
> file:///Users/dakshsemwal/StudioProjects/eazy-android/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/eazyupdates/AndroidCompose.kt:9:37
> 5 type arguments expected for interface CommonExtension<BuildFeaturesT
> : BuildFeatures, BuildTypeT : BuildType, DefaultConfigT :
> DefaultConfig, ProductFlavorT : ProductFlavor, AndroidResourcesT :
> AndroidResources>

I believe the issue is with how I've used CommonExtension in my Kotlin DSL files. Specifically, the problem occurs in these function definitions:

```kotlin
internal fun Project.configureAndroidCompose(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *>
) {
    val libs = extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")

    commonExtension.apply {
        buildFeatures {
            compose = true
            viewBinding = true
        }

        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.findVersion("androidx-compose").get().toString()
        }

        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs
        }
    }
}
```

and

```kotlin
fun Project.configureFlavors(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *>
) {
    commonExtension.apply {
        flavorDimensions += FlavorDimension.environment.name
        productFlavors {
            Flavor.values().forEach {
                create(it.name) {
                    dimension = it.dimension.name
                    buildConfigField("String", "host", it.host)
                }
            }
        }
        testOptions {
            unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
            unitTests.isIncludeAndroidResources = true
            unitTests.all {
                it.useJUnitPlatform()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both functions, I pass CommonExtension as an argument with four wildcards for its generic types. I had no issues prior to the Gradle upgrade.

My main questions are:

Why am I receiving this error message, and what does it mean?
What changes might have occurred between Gradle 8.0.2 and 8.1.1 that could lead to this issue?
I appreciate any insight or advice on how to resolve this build failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Migration to 8.1.1

To solve it just add one more `*` to `CommonExtension`.

Replace all:

```kotlin
commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *>
```

with:

```kotlin
commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *>
```

Seems like API was changed to help with [Automatic per-app language support](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#automatic-per-app-languages).

[Diff of changes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/655ea2cf3bd8337a8a2172446a4c4713040d7df0%5E%21/#F2).

---

#### Migration to 8.3.0 (Update)

For migration to 8.3.0 you have to add sixth `*` like in migration to 8.1.1

```kotlin
commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *, *>
```

[Diff of changes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/d44f5b98cd5530eceb230e0d151ad96c4277f78d%5E%21/#F4).